# Sorting from Today to Yesterday

Tags: mysql

I am trying to order a query by date, from today until yesterday.  So far I can do this with two queries

```
SELECT title, premiered 
FROM movies 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(premiered, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') 
ORDER BY MONTH(premiered) ASC, DAY(premiered) ASC
```

Then

```
SELECT title, premiered 
FROM movies 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(premiered, '%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') 
ORDER BY MONTH(premiered) ASC, DAY(premiered) ASC
```

I can not seem to combine these two queries and have the output sorted correctly.

Comment: is permiered a datetime field?

Comment: *to order a query by date, from today until yesterday* Does this means that there is no data with `premiered` date values other than today or yesterday dates?

Comment: My apologies my answer was for mssql not mysql. forpas has it right

Answer (score 1):

You want `premiered` to have a difference from `CURRENT_DATE` 0 or 1 days:

```
SELECT title, premiered 
FROM movies 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, premiered) IN (0, 1)
ORDER BY premiered
```

Edit for the new requirement:

```
SELECT title, premiered 
FROM movies 
WHERE premiered BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
ORDER BY premiered
```